# Switching between 2 power sources using just a switch

Tags: power

So, recently while making a project, I thought of a way to switch between 2 power sources just using a single 3 pin slide switch. 
Would something like the image below work?
Where I connect a common ground to the middle pin and 1 power source to each other pin. [image: Image of 3 pin slide switch connected to 2 power sources]

Comment: Where does the thing you're providing power to fit into this? As drawn, you're just shorting one power source or the other to ground. That's going to burn out your switch or burn out the power source. And it won't power anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As drawn, the commmon terminal of the switch will be powered by either "Power Source 1" or "Power Source 2" -- so connect the common terminal to the positive terminal of the load, not GND.

Circuitlab doesn't have a slide switch symbol, I'm using SW1 (a SPDT switch) to represent your slide switch. The center terminal of your slide switch is the common terminal of SW1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQGwzC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The generic load is represented by resistor R1 and LED D1, and the two power sources are represented by V1 and V2. Note that both power sources share a common ground return from the load.